# Reliably tracking changes made by Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, concurrency, transactions

I'm using a `PostUpdateEventListener` registered via

```
registry.appendListeners(EventType.POST_COMMIT_UPDATE, listener)
```

and a few other listeners in order to track changes made by Hibernate. This works perfectly, however, I see a problem there:

Let's say, for tracking some `amount` by `id`, I simply execute

```
 amountByIdConcurrentMap.put(id, amount);
```

on every `POST_COMMIT_UPDATE` (let's ignore other operations). The problem is that this call happens *some time after the commit*. So with two commits  writing the same entity shortly one after the other, I can receive the events in the *wrong order*, ending up with the older `amount` stored.

- Is this really possible or are the operations synchronized somehow?
- Is there a way how to prevent or at least detect such situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two questions and a proposal later

1. Are you sure, that you need this optimization. Why not fetch the amount as it is written to the database by querying there. What gives you reason to work with caching.
2. How do you make sure, that the calculation of the amount before writing it to the database is properly synchronized, so that multiple threads or probably nodes do not use old data to calculate the amount and therefore overwrite the result of a later calculation?

I suppose you handle question number 2 right. Then you have to options:

1. Pessimistic locking, that means that immediatly before the commit you can exclusively update your cache without concurrency issues.
2. Optimistic locking: In that case you have a kind of timestamp or counter in your database-record you can also put into the cache together with the amount. This value you can use to find out, what the more recent value is.

Comment: I'm actually using optimistic locking, so possibly I need nothing but to compare the timestamps like `map.compute(id, (k, v) -> v==null || timestamp.isAfter(v.timestamp) ? new Value(timestamp, amount) : v)`. This sounds really simple.

Comment: maartinus Ok, but make sure to do this change exclusively. Between isAfter and setting the value another thread could change the content

Comment: maartinus and, in a clustered environment, be aware that you might not see the latest value in the cache, if it is not distributed, like infinispan.

Comment: Thanks! I guess, this all should go well. By `map`, I meant `concurrentMap` (which synchronizes `compute` on the key). The values I get come from the `PostUpdateEvent#newState` and are private to a `Session`. I'm not using clustering yet, and I'm aware that it gets complicated.

Answer (score 2):

No, there are no ordering guarantees, so you'll have to take care to ensure proper synchronization manually.

If the real problem you are solving is caching of entity state and if it is suitable to use second-level cache for the entity in question, then you would get everything out of the box by enabling the L2 cache.

Otherwise, instead of updating the map from the update listeners directly, you could submit tasks to an Executor or messaging system that would asynchronously start a new transaction and `select for update` the amount for the given id from the database. Then update the map in the same transaction while holding the corresponding row lock in the db, so that map updates for the same id are done serially.

Comment: When the L2 cache can do it better, then it must use some better mechanism than interceptors/listeners, mustn't it? `+++` The other answer [may lead to a simple solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47254385/reliably-tracking-changes-made-by-hibernate#comment81593858_47318434), what do you think?

Comment: @maaartinus To ensure consistency L2 cache uses soft locks for read-write cache and relies on XA protocol for transactional cache, it does not use entity update listeners.

Comment: Regarding the other answer, if you take a look at the edit history of my answer, I initially also suggested option 1, but then I realized that it means publishing the change to the map before committing the transaction, so I removed it. Regarding timestamps, they can still be the same for both concurrent updates, plus it is hard to guarantee that their order would correspond to the order in which two concurrent transactions are actually committed.

Comment: But if you don't use clustering, storing a counter together with the amount in the cache, as suggested by @aschoerk, looks like a good idea.

Comment: One thing I don't understand at all: Why select *for update*? If I'd go to the DB, I'd just 1. listen for POST_COMMIT_UPDATE, 2. fetch all changes entities. I'd hope, this should be enough for *avoiding working with the overwritten* state. Updating the map is no problem at all, as a `ConcurrentMap` takes care of itself (I'm not going to send the data to some remote DB requiring additional synchronization).

Comment: @maaartinus I suggested a more general approach with synchronization on the db level that should cover most cases. Of course, if you prevent possible race conditions between re-reading the data and updating the map by synchronizing on something else, that is also fine.